# Invoking a function added to the function prototype

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently confused with function.prototype. I've seen this type of code:

```
define([], function() {
    function HomeViewModel(route) {
        this.message = ko.observable('Welcome to Home!');
        }

        HomeViewModel.prototype.doSomething = function() {
            this.message('You invoked doSomething() on the viewmodel.');
        };

        return HomeViewModel;
    }
}
```

How is it that we can add a function in a function's prototype? I've also did some reading here: [Function.protoype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype). In the Description portion, it states that:

> Function objects inherit from Function.prototype.  Function.prototype cannot be modified.

But the code above looks like it is adding a function in the function prototype. I've tested and the code above returns *function HomeViewModel()*. So how do you call the *HomeViewModel.prototype.doSomething* from the return value or outside of the actual function?

Comment: Please remove the syntax errors in code you have a question about. Also, I am pretty sure you have your curly braces in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the capitalisation between *function* and `Function`: in Javascript, you can absolutely add methods to a functions' prototype, you just cannot add methods to the `Function.prototype` — `Function` being the "base class" with the name *Function*, where lots of built-in methods live that all functions share.

If you add a method to an objects prototype, you call it just as you would call a method you added in the constructor:

```
function Test() {
  this.myMethod = function() {
    return true;
  }
}

t = new Test();
t.myMethod();
```

With a method added to the prototype:

```
function Test() {
}

Test.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  return true;
}

t = new Test();
t.myMethod();
```

So where's the difference? If you add a method within your constructor, every object created from that constructor gets its own unique copy of that method:

```
function Test() {
  this.myMethod = ko.observable();
}

a = new Test();
b = new Test();
a.myMethod('foo');
b.myMethod(); // returns undefined
```

On the other hand, methods you add to the prototype are *shared* between all objects created from that constructor:

```
function Test() {
}

Test.prototype.myMethod = ko.observable();

a = new Test();
b = new Test();
a.myMethod('foo');
b.myMethod(); // returns 'foo'
```

Comment: You *can* add methods to Function prototype, although it would seldom be a good idea.